# Show and hide div onclick button

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, hide, show

How can I show and hide a div (content) with a click on a button?

Here some code:

```
<button class="btn btn-default">Text</button>
<div class="div-to-hide">Some content</div>
```

Comment: this is a very broad question, please share some code you have and describe what is not working and how it should work

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this by using [jQuery's toggle function](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) like `<button class="button" onclick="$('#target').toggle();">Show/Hide</button>`

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/W2vh3/